# When calling a function from a python module in my main script it causes the program to just end. Why is this happening and how to fix?

Tags: python, module, command-line-arguments

In my main script I have an outer function with an inner function containing an `if`, `elif`, and `else` condition. I won't explain the entire program here yet. Anyways when the user input is "1" for the main script it should execute the rps_main() function of module 1 but its not doing it.

I am suspecting that it has something to do with this code block I have at the bottom of module 1, which I also have in bottom of my main script. How do I add the functionality of it being callable in my main script while retaining the ability to still be ran alone with the command line argument name input? Another problem I haven't figured out is how to keep the command line argument name input from main script to transfer to module 1, and back the main script as I navigate?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Provides a personalized RPS game experience."
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-n", "--name", metavar="name",
        required=True, help="The name of the person playing the game."
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    rock_paper_scissors = rps_main(args.name)
    rock_paper_scissors()
```

ChatGPT does not help fix my program. Here is the code of the module below.

```
import sys
import random
from enum import Enum

name = "None"

def rps_main(name):
    game_count = 0
    player_wins = 0
    python_wins = 0

    def play_rps():
        nonlocal name
        nonlocal player_wins
        nonlocal python_wins

        class RPS(Enum):
            ROCK = 1
            PAPER = 2
            SCISSORS = 3

        playerchoice = input(
            f"\n{name}, please enter... \n1 for Rock,\n2 for Paper, or \n3 for Scissors:\n\n")

        if playerchoice not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
            print(f"{name}, please enter 1, 2, or 3.")
            return play_rps()

        player = int(playerchoice)

        computerchoice = random.choice("123")

        computer = int(computerchoice)

        print(f"\n{name}, you chose {
              str(RPS(player)).replace('RPS.', '').title()}.")
        print(
            f"Python chose {str(RPS(computer)).replace('RPS.', '').title()}.\n"
        )

        def decide_winner(player, computer):
            nonlocal name
            nonlocal player_wins
            nonlocal python_wins
            if player == 1 and computer == 3:
                player_wins += 1
                return f" {name}, you win!"
            elif player == 2 and computer == 1:
                player_wins += 1
                return f" {name}, you win!"
            elif player == 3 and computer == 2:
                player_wins += 1
                return f" {name}, you win!"
            elif player == computer:
                return " Tie game!"
            else:
                python_wins += 1
                return f" Python wins!\nSorry, {name}.."

        game_result = decide_winner(player, computer)

        print(game_result)

        nonlocal game_count
        game_count += 1

        print(f"\nGame count: {game_count}")
        print(f"\n{name}'s wins: {player_wins}")
        print(f"\nPython wins: {python_wins}")

        print(f"\nPlay again, {name}?")

        while True:
            playagain = input("\nY for Yes or \nQ to Quit\n")
            if playagain.lower() not in ["y", "q"]:
                continue
            else:
                break

        if playagain.lower() == "y":
            return play_rps()
        else:
            print("\n")
            print("Thank you for playing!\n")
            sys.exit(f"Bye {name}! ")

    return play_rps
```

The command line stuff goes below here after return play_rps

Comment: `__name__==__main__` is how it should be. It would be helpful if you showed minimal working example

Comment: What does the *rps()* function do?

Comment: I added it to the main post now

Comment: Your return either *play_rps* or *play_rps()* from *rps_main()* One of those is the wrong choice

Comment: Everything is resolved and figured it now. I didnt add the () for the play_rps, since the function wasn't being called without it. Thanks!